# Disable an input after click and validation occurs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input

I'm trying to disable an input in a form, but only after validation of fields.

```
function valJomclAddForm() {
    f = document.jomclForm;
    document.formvalidator.setHandler('list', function (value) {            
        return (value != -1);
    });     
    if (document.formvalidator.isValid(f)) {

        if(document.getElementById('membership6') === null) {
            return false;
        }           
        jQuery('input#submit').val('Publishing...');
        jQuery('input#submit').prop('disabled', true);
        return true;

    } else {
        //alert
    }
}
```

but when function gets here:

```
jQuery('input#submit').prop('disabled', true);
return true;
```

Function stops, change input value to "Publishing" but doesn't publish, doesn't get the "return true"

Unless I remove `jQuery('input#submit').prop('disabled', true);`then function return true and publish this...

Why does this not work?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what error do you get in your console?

Comment: Thats the strange, I don't get any error...

Comment: doesnt make sense something else is interrupting this. If you want I can help you through Teamviewer.

Comment: Hi @CodeGodie, sorry for long ausent... Yes, please if you can help me I would be very appreciated!

How can I reach you?